# How to set final value of explicit CA Animation with Delay

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I've got a explicit animation where I want to set the final value so that the object stays at the end point. But how I can achieve this on a delayed animation: Here's the code:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveAnimation.duration = 0.3;
    moveAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    moveAnimation.repeatCount = 1;

    // Bounce
    [moveAnimation setValues:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[self getCoordinatePointForAnimationWithRadius:0 withIndex:i]],
                         [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[self getCoordinatePointForAnimationWithRadius:radius + 10 withIndex:i]],
                         [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[self getCoordinatePointForAnimationWithRadius:radius - 5 withIndex:i]],
                         [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[self getCoordinatePointForAnimationWithRadius:radius withIndex:i]], nil]];

    [moveAnimation setKeyTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.75],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil]];

    [moveAnimation setTimingFunctions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                       [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut], nil]];



    moveAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1 + (0.1 * i);


    [layer addAnimation:opacityAnimation forKey:@"opacityAnimationUp"];
    [layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:@"moveAnimationUp"];

// That's not working correctly because of the delay
    [layer setOpacity:1.0];
    [layer setPosition:[self getCoordinatePointForAnimationWithRadius:radius withIndex:i]];
```

Thanks!

Best regards from Germany, 
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the only thing missing is a backwards fill mode. That will cause the animation to display the first value as soon as it's added, even if the actual animation is delayed:

```
moveAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
```

Comment: Wow that made it. Thanks David (+1)